# Can't get nxlog to logstash with SSL working

Tags: ssl, openssl, logstash, nxlog

I've bought a certificate from DigiCert. So I got the files; DigiCertCA.crt, mydomain_com.crt mydomain_com.key

I changed my logstash config to this;

```
tcp {
    type => "AppLog"
    port => 5656
    host => "mydomain.com"
    ssl_cacert => "C:/Certificates/DigiCertCA.crt"
    ssl_cert => "C:/Certificates/mydomain_com.crt"
    ssl_key => "C:/Certificates/mydomain_com.key"
    ssl_enable => true
    ssl_verify => true
}
```

And then changed my nxlog config to this (running on different machine):

```
<Output App_Out>
    Module      om_ssl
    Host        mydomain.com
    Port        5656
    CAFile      C:\NxLogCerts\DigiCertCA.crt
    CertFile    C:\NxLogCerts\mydomain_com.crt
    OutputType  LineBased
</Output>
```

And I've tried many different parameters, removed some, added some like AllowUntrusted etc on both side. No luck.

Tested with openssl;

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile DigiCertCA.pem -connect mydomain.com:5960
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CountryCode, ST = State, L = City, O = CompanyName AS, CN = mydomain.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CountryCode/ST=State/L=City/O=CompanyName/CN=mydomain.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERTIFICATE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=CountryCode/ST=State/L=City/O=XompanyName/CN=mydomain.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1801 bytes and written 462 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: -----------Removed
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: -----------Removed
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1441375513
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Which seems good..?

Any pointers to find out what the acutal problem is? Am I doing it wrong?

EDIT:
Ofcourse I forgot the error messages;
On the nxlog-client sending to logstash

```
2015-09-04 16:17:21 INFO nxlog-ce-2.9.1347 started
2015-09-04 16:17:21 INFO connecting to mydomain.com:5960
2015-09-04 16:17:21 INFO successfully connected to mydomain.com:5960
2015-09-04 16:17:21 INFO reconnecting in 1 seconds
2015-09-04 16:17:21 ERROR SSL certificate verification failed: unable to get issuer certificate (err: 2)
2015-09-04 16:17:22 INFO connecting to mydomain.com:5960
2015-09-04 16:17:22 INFO successfully connected to mydomain.com:5960
2015-09-04 16:17:22 INFO reconnecting in 1 seconds
2015-09-04 16:17:22 ERROR SSL certificate verification failed: unable to get issuer certificate (err: 2)
```

And on the logstash server

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-09-04T16:25:52.976000+0200", :message=>"SSL Error", :exception=>#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:238:in `accept'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/jopenssl19/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:142:in `accept'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-tcp-1.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb:182:in `run_server'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-tcp-1.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb:170:in `run'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:177:in `inputworker'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:171:in `start_input'"], :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2015-09-04T16:25:53.992000+0200", :message=>"SSL Error", :exception=>#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:238:in `accept'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/jopenssl19/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:142:in `accept'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-tcp-1.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb:182:in `run_server'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-tcp-1.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb:170:in `run'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:177:in `inputworker'", "C:/elkstack/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:171:in `start_input'"], :level=>:error}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I can't really tell what's wrong since you have not posted any error messages.
- Buying certificates for this was a waste of money. You should create your own CA cert (with openssl for instance) and then generate the cert+key pair for each entity. There are plenty of howtos on the net.
- om_ssl usually needs *CertKeyFile* together with *CertFile*.
- The *openssl s_client* test you ran does not verify (there is a *-verify* switch for that), on the other hand certificate verification is turned on at both ends.
- Try with *AllowUntrusted TRUE* to see if that helps.

Comment: I "inherited" this, so the buying of the certificates wasn't my call. Thanks for the tip about -verify for s_client. I've already tried with AllowUntrusted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with awesant and logstash, I also am using DigiCert certeficates. In my case the problem was that one of the endpoints didn't have the complete certificate chain.

I created a file 'x' and have put in there the DigiCertCA.crt and TrustedRoot.crt contents and using that file as the CA certificate everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: Okey, so how do I generate the TrustedRoot.crt? Is it a combination of DigiCertCA and the mydomain.crt? Sorry but I'm not really good at this certificate-stuff.

Comment: @hayer you can ot generate the TrustedRoot.crt. There are two possibilities, digicert could sent all the certificate chain in the file DigiCertCA.crt or they sent you the file TrustedRoot.crt when they created your certificate.

run the following command: **openssl verify -CAfile DigiCertCA.crt my_certeficate.crt**

if all the chain is in there you will receive an ok message and you have a problem diffrent than mine, otherwise you will have to look for file TrustedRoot.crt (maybe DigiCert sent it to you with other certificate)